# KML layer not being added in android app

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I am trying to add a layer of 2000 locations over a map. The code should be working, it shows the try block that adds the KML layer completing, but nothing shows up on the map.

On further inspection, i beleive it must be a problem with the KML file, which i generated in google maps. This is because an example KML file i downloaded works perfectly, just not the one I generated?

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private boolean gotLocation = false;
GPSTracker gps;
double latitude;
double longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    gps = new GPSTracker(this);
    latitude = gps.getLatitude();
    longitude = gps.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(this, "WE HAVE GOT YOUR LOCATION: LATITUDE = " + latitude + "LONGITUDE = " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Current Position"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));;

    try {
        KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.vha, getApplicationContext());
        layer.addLayerToMap();
        Log.v("Maps", "We should have added layer");
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("Maps", "Pull parser exception");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("Maps", "IO exception");

    }

}
```

}

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
<Document>
    <name>VHA</name>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <Folder>
        <name>VHA</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Aberdeen VA Clinic</name>
            <description><![CDATA[Address: 2301 8th Ave. NE, Suite 225   Aberdeen, SD 57401<br>State: SD<br>Phone: 605-229-3500<br>Zip: 57401]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#icon-1899-0288D1</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <Data name='Address'>
                    <value>2301 8th Ave. NE, Suite 225   Aberdeen, SD 57401</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='State'>
                    <value>SD</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Phone'>
                    <value>605-229-3500</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Zip'>
                    <value>57401</value>
                </Data>
            </ExtendedData>
            <address>2301 8th Ave. NE, Suite 225   Aberdeen, SD 57401</address>
        </Placemark>}
```

Comment: Ok on futher inspection, it seems no matter how i export to KML file from google maps, when i then try to import the kml file just exported, i get this error: The file contains invalid or unsupported data, or the file is too large to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for anyone else that ever has this problem, google can create a KML file from a csv file of addresses, but it can't read it. You have to convert the addresses in csv file to lat/long first, and then create the kml file.